# Monero Fork: Blocks are not mining for more than 20 Hrs

Tags: mining, monero-forks

I have forked Monero V0.13.0.4 and changed the network ID and genesis tx. The Blockchain was running fine for a week, after that I noticed that there were some serious delays in the block creation time, sometimes it took 3hrs to mine a block. Day by day, the time delay for block creation has increased, now it's been more than 20hrs and the blocks are not yet mined.

Currently the blockchain is running on Monero v7. Below is the detailed info about the network.

Network Hashrate: `5.083 MH/s`
Total Pool Hashrate: `6.03 MH/s`
Difficulty: `609932199`
Block Height: `10498`

I have also noticed that the blocks created after the delayed time are created pretty quickly. The delay in block creation is happening once in a day.

Any help regarding this will be really helpful.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: Have you updated your pool code correctly?

Comment: Yes, I have updated the pool with latest code.

Comment: And the pool is mining (finding) and submitting blocks? Because you stated the pool has a higher hashrate than the network, which means it should be submitting blocks. But if it's submitting bad blocks, there's your problem.

Comment: Yes, the pools are submitting blocks. Does pools can submit bad blocks? If so is it because of wrong pool config? How we can get rid of these kind of issues?

Comment: If your pool/miners are hashing with the wrong CN version, they will regularly submit bad blocks. That's why I asked if you'd updated the pool with the same version as your daemon is running. E.g. you state in the question your fork is running Monero v7, so your pool and miners have to be using the exact same version of CN that was in Monero v7 (which is CN variant 1). Otherwise, the pool will be submitting bad blocks and your chain wont grow.

Comment: Yes, the pool is up to date. The pool is using CN variant 1. It looks like there is something to do with the network difficulty and hashrate. I have stopped all the pools and mining but the network hashrate and difficulty doesn't drop.

Comment: Firstly, you have to wait some time for network difficulty to adjust. This won't happen immediately after stopping your pools/miners. Second, have you changed the network byte and p2p ports in your fork? Have you checked nothing else is connected when your pools are shutdown?

Comment: Yes, I have changed the network byte and p2p ports in my fork. The p2p port I am using is 19090. Yes no other miners are connected while the pools are in shutdown.

Comment: Also I have noticed one more thing, After stopping all the pools I have created a new pool and buy some hash power from nicehash and suddenly the blocks started mining. The blocks we're mined perfectly for 12 hrs. After that the pool didn't find any blocks it's been 4 hours.

Comment: When I restart the pool the blocks started mining, looks strange

Comment: If it's working with purchased NH then your miners were the problem.

Comment: There is only one miner in the pool and that is ran by me with nicehash hash power. It runs fine for 10 to 12 hrs and stopped mining blocks. But when I restart the pool the miner start mining blocks

Comment: You stated above you *bought* from NH, not sold. When you buy, someone else is mining and sending hashes to your pool.